# Derivatives of Trace of $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ Matrices by Another $\operatorname{SU}(2)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, lie-groups, matrix-calculus, monte-carlo

In short, my question is how do I take derivatives of functions that look like,
$$\mathrm{Tr}(UM)$$ or $$\mathrm{Tr}(U^{\dagger}M)$$  by $U$ where $U$ and $M$ are $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ matrices. The longer story is that I am trying to derive force terms that are used in hybrid Monte Carlo simulations. A lot of that is physics so I don't want to post most of that here. With that being said, if this is an example of an XY problem, I would love some input. Most papers that I have come across haven't done a very good job of explaining exactly how these terms are derived. So, in longer format, the derivative that I am trying to take is of the following function:
$$S = \frac{4}{g^2}\sum_{x,\mu < \nu}\left( 1 -\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}\left(U_{\mu}(x)U_{\nu}(x+a\hat{e}_{\mu})U_{\mu}^{\dagger}(x+a\hat{e}_{\nu})U_{\nu}^{\dagger}(x)\right) \right) $$
with respect to $A_{\mu}(x)$ where $A_{\mu}(x) = \sum_aA_{\mu}^a(x)\sigma^a$ where $\sigma^a$ are the Pauli matrices so that $A_{\mu}(x)$ is Hermitian. The matrices $U$ are defined by the $A$ matrices as $U_{\mu}(x) = e^{igA_{\mu}(x)}$. $\mu$ and $\nu$ are indices that run from $1$ to $4$. Of course what I'm really trying to find is
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial A_{\mu}(x)}$$ but that simplfies with the chain rule to
$$  \frac{\partial U_{\mu}(x)}{\partial A_{\mu}(x)} \frac{\partial S}{\partial U_{\mu}(x)} = igU_{\mu}(x)\frac{\partial S}{\partial U_{\mu}(x)} $$.

Comment: I'm not sure the chain rule applies to this type of problem. Can you try to rewrite the question so it really stays within maths? I am not sure for example how you index a matrix with only one indice.

Comment: So $U_{\mu}(x)$ is one 2x2 matrix. There are 4 matrices for every position $x$. The index is mostly irrelevant to the matrix itself. See the abbreviated explanation at the top of the post. Sorry that there are so many indices floating around that are largely irrelevant to the problem at hand. That's why I gave the abbreviated version at the beginning.  The $\mu$ index is a spacetime index. $a$ is a triplet index.

Comment: So $U_{\mu}(x)$, $U_{\nu}(x+a\hat{e}_{\mu})$, $U_{\mu}^{\dagger}(x+a\hat{e}_{\nu})$, $U_{\nu}^{\dagger}(x)$ are four independent matrices?

Comment: That's correct, unless you can orient them in such a way that they contain $U_{\mu}(x)$ or $U_{\mu}^{\dagger}(x)$, which you can do because you're summing over all x. Take for example the site $x-ae_{\nu}$. The term in the sum becomes $U_{\mu}(x-a\hat{e}_{\nu})U_{\nu}(x-a\hat{e}_{\nu}+a\hat{e}_{\mu})U_{\mu}^{\dagger}(x)U_{\nu}(x-a\hat{e}_{\nu})$.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\mbrace#1{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right\rbrace}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let $c\in\R{4}$ be an arbitrary vector and construct the associated quaternion
$$\eqalign{
c &= \mbrace{c_0\\c_1\\c_2\\c_3} \qiq
C &= \m{c_0+ic_1 & c_2+ic_3\\\hline -c_2+ic_3 & c_0-ic_1} \\
}$$
which can also be written with respect to a basis consisting of Pauli matrices $\{\s_k\}$
$$\eqalign{
C &= s_0\,\s_0 + s_1\,\s_1 + s_2\,\s_2 + s_2\,\s_2 \\
s_0 &= c_0, \quad{\rm but}\quad s_k \ne c_k\;\:\{{\rm for}\;k=1,2,3\} \\
}$$
Normalizing the vector generates a unit quaternion, i.e. an $SU(2)$ matrix $$\eqalign{
&u = \frac{c}{\|c\|} = \mbrace{u_0\\u_1\\u_2\\u_3} \qiq
U = \m{u_0+iu_1 & u_2+iu_3\\\hline-u_2+iu_3 & u_0-iu_1} \\
&U^\dagger U = I, \qquad
\det(U) = (u_0^2+u_1^2)+(u_2^2+u_3^2) = \o \\
}$$
Let's use a colon to denote the matrix inner product
$$\eqalign{
C:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{C^TB} \\
C:B &= B:C \qquad \{ {\rm \,commutes\,} \} \\
C^*:C &= \frob{C}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm \,Frobenius\;norm\,} \} \\
}$$
The vector and matrix representations of two arbitrary quaternions
satisfy
$$\eqalign{
C^*:B \;=\; 2\,c:b \;=\; 2\,b:c \;=\; B^*:C \\
}$$
and therefore
$$\eqalign{
\frob{C} &= \sqrt{2}\:\frob{c}
 \qiq U = \frac{C}{\frob{c}} = \sqrt{2}\,\LR{\frac{C}{\frob{C}}} \\
\frob{U} &= \sqrt{2} \\
}$$
Using the quotient rule, the differential of the unit vector can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
du &= \LR{\frac{I-uu^T}{\|c\|}} dc \\
}$$
This means that the updated vector $\LR{u_+=u+du}$ remains a unit vector and therefore corresponds to an updated $SU(2)$ matrix.

Finally, if you define the quaternion
$$B=M^\dagger \qiq B^*=M^T$$
then your first function can be dispatched as follows
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{MU} \\
 &= B^*:U \\
 &= 2\,b:u \qquad \{ {\rm vector\;form} \} \\
\\
d\phi &= 2\,b : du \\
  &= 2\,b : \LR{\frac{I-uu^T}{\|c\|}}dc \\
  &= 2 \LR{\frac{I-uu^T}{\|c\|}}b : dc \\
\\
\grad{\phi}{c} &= 2 \LR{\frac{I-uu^T}{\|c\|}}b \\
}$$
This is the gradient of the function with respect to an **unconstrained** $\R{4}$ vector, which is not what you asked for but is what you need if you plan to do any sort of optimization.

Once the optimal vector is found, it is trivial to recover the corresponding $\,U\in SU(2)$

However, if you really, really want the gradient with respect to $U\,$ then here it is
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{U} &= B^* \\
}$$
The problem with this gradient is that it accommodates movement in *any* direction, including those which destroy the unitarity of $U$.

But if you're careful to only choose directions which preserve
unitarity (don't ask me how), then this gradient could be useful.

Comment: Preserving unitarity is not an issue. The result simple has to be traceless Hermitian. The unitary bit comes from being exponentiated. Traceless $2\times2$ anti-Hermitian matrices are generators of $SU(2)$. Also since you mention optimization, that's not what I'm going for here. Instead, what I am trying to do is generate new configurations for sampling using the [leapfrog method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_Monte_Carlo).

Comment: I believe that you confused my $A$ matrix for your own $A_\mu$ matrices, so I changed the name of my variable to $C$. The first paragraph of your post clearly indicates that $U$ should be unitary, so I assumed that was an important constraint (and I really didn't understand the rest of the post).